# UE4 4.26 on mac: undefined symbols Z_Construct_UClass_UPhysicalMaterial

Tags: c++, linker, unreal-engine4

trying to get my project up and running on macos big sur, but I'm facing a linking error (full paste here : https://pastebin.com/raw/qt7qkjYu):

```
[10/13] Link UE4Editor-LastRenegade.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Z_Construct_UClass_UPhysicalMaterial()", referenced from:
      Z_Construct_UClass_ULRNBasePhysicalMaterial_Statics::DependentSingletons in LRNBasePhysicalMaterial.gen.cpp.o
  "UPhysicalMaterial::GetPrivateStaticClass()", referenced from:

[...]

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I'm overriding a physical material to get useful info from raycasts:

```cpp
UCLASS()
class LASTRENEGADE_API ULRNBasePhysicalMaterial : public UPhysicalMaterial
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    ULRNBasePhysicalMaterial(); (defined in a cpp file)

public:
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly)
    class USoundBase* ImpactSFX;
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly)
    class UParticleSystem* ImpactVFX;
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly)
    class UMaterialInterface* ImpactDecal;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in 4.26: you need to add `PhysicsCore` to your MyGame.Build.cs